# Помогите с пунктуацией в тексте

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

Добрый день, Татьяна. Я очень сильно извиняюсь,но,так как у нас с вами сложилась работа в формате "только рассчитайте мне тур и проконсультируйте по телефону", то все рассчёты для вас я смогу сделать только при личной встрече в нашем офисе. Вы,к сожалению, не находите времени подойти к нам в офис, после чего в итоге покупаете тур в других агентствах по моим подборкам, Увы, сейчас не располагаю большим количеством времени, т.к. идет раннее бронирование по Турции. В офисе очень много туристов, которые уже готовы приобретать путевки именно у меня! Прошу меня понять правильно, я как профессионал, очень ценю свое рабочее время. Я не могу подобными рассчётами оставить без внимания туристов, которые записаны ко мне на встречу.

Answer (score 2):

Оставляя вопросы пунктуации на рассмотрение абвг, хочу обратить Ваше внимание на стилистику этого документа.

- *Извиняюсь* — разговорный стиль, лучше сказать "извините", "прошу прощения", "примите мои извинения".
- В официальных письмах при персональном обращении лучше писать *Вы* с прописной буквы.
- *"Вы, к сожалению, не находите времени подойти к нам в офис, после чего в итоге покупаете тур в других агентствах по моим подборкам."* "Покупаете тур" —  если речь идет о повторяющейся ситуации, то желательно это выразить каким-либо образом, например "всегда покупаете тур", "покупаете туры".
- *"...Не могу подобными расчётами оставить без внимания туристов"* — требует переделки. Как варианты: "не могу из-за подобных расчётов оставить без внимания туристов";  "не могу заниматься подобными расчётами и оставить без внимания туристов".
- Называть туристами клиентов турагентства, еще не отправившихся в путешествие, тоже не совсем верно. Ну разве что они известны как заядлые туристы... Возможно, это профессиональный сленг (так врач называет больными всех пришедших к нему на прием), но Вы ведь адресуете это письмо не коллеге.

Дополнение

Обнаружил еще одну ошибку, на этот раз смысловую. Мысль выражена неверно: *так как у нас система работы по телефону, то Вам придется прийти к нам в офисе.* Бессмыслица, согласитесь. Варианты исправления:

**Примите мои извинения, но мы не можем продолжать работать в формате "только рассчитайте мне тур и проконсультируйте по телефону", поэтому все расчёты для Вас я смогу сделать только при личной встрече в нашем офисе."**

**Примите мои извинения, но так как мы не можем продолжать работать в формате "только рассчитайте мне тур и проконсультируйте по телефону", то все расчёты для Вас я смогу сделать только при личной встрече в нашем офисе."**

Небольшое уточнение: наверно, просто закралась ошибка, так сказать, недочет при редактировании: слово "расчет" пишется с одной буквой эс, а "рассчитывать" (все правильно!) с двумя. В первом случае корень -чет-, а в другом -счит- в союзе с приставкой рас-.

Comment: @РВМ Спасибо за правку. Я автоматически скопировал слова из вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, Татьяна. Я очень сильно извиняюсь, но так как у нас с Вами сложилась работа в формате "только рассчитайте мне тур и проконсультируйте по телефону", то все расчёты для Вас я смогу сделать только при личной встрече в нашем офисе. Вы, к сожалению, не находите времени подойти к нам в офис, после чего в итоге покупаете тур в других агентствах по моим подборкам. Увы, сейчас не располагаю большим количеством времени, так как идет раннее бронирование по Турции. В офисе очень много туристов, которые уже готовы приобретать путевки именно у меня! Прошу меня понять правильно: я, как профессионал, очень ценю свое рабочее время; я не могу подобными расчётами оставить без внимания туристов, которые записаны ко мне на встречу.

1) Я очень сильно извиняюсь, но так как у нас с вами сложилась работа в формате "только рассчитайте мне тур и проконсультируйте по телефону", то все расчёты для Вас я смогу сделать только при личной встрече в нашем офисе.

В этом предложении запятая перед так как не нужна, потому что в последней придаточной части появилось соотносительное слово то.

2) Прошу меня понять правильно: я, как профессионал, очень ценю свое рабочее время; я не могу подобными расчётами оставить без внимания туристов, которые записаны ко мне на встречу.

В этом предложении после слова правильно вместо запятой лучше поставить двоеточие, так как раскрывается суть начала предложения (прошу меня понять правильно); также перед как стоит запятая, потому что здесь есть значение причины (почему очень ценю свое рабочее время? Потому что я профессионал).

Также стоит обратить Ваше внимание на то, что слово расчет пишется с одной с.

Comment: В офисе очень много туристов, которые уже готовы приобретать путевки именно у меня! ======== Восклицание чем объясните? И наоборот, здесь напрашивается: «Добрый день, Татьяна.»

Comment: Чем  объяснить восклицание? Нужно спросить автора.                "Добрый день, Татьяна". Точка в этом предложении вполне уместна. В своем ответе я исправил только пунктуационные и орфографические ошибки в тексте, приведенном автором вопроса.

Comment: Точка уместна, а восклицательный знак авторский, это крик души!